# How does changing the encoding from US-ASCII to UTF-16 change the function of code?

Tags: character-encoding, ascii, utf-16

Trying to understand encoding better. As far as I understand UTF-16 is 16 bit and ASCII is 32 bit, so it will send twice the amount of packets if the encoding is changed to UTF-16? Is there any other ways that it will change the function of the code?

Also, I'm getting an error when I change the encoding, are there still packets being sent?

Comment: ASCII is 8 bit. UTF-16 is _mostly_ 16 bit, but it is actually a variable-length encoding, which means that one character might require more than 16 bits.

Comment: Ok so I was completely wrong.. So is it the opposite to what I was thinking, and it will send half as many packets?

Comment: If you have 10 characters and send them as ASCII, they will take up 80 bits. If you send them as UTF-16, they will take up at least 160 bits.

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks. Also if the browser returns with a 400 status error, are the packets still sent?

Comment: Hard to tell - the 400 status code just says that the server didn't understand the data you tried to send it. You could use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's actually being sent.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> Ok so I was completely wrong.. the 400 status code just says that the server didn't understand the data you tried to send it. You could use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to see what's actually being sent.